# Instruct Laravel to catch Class X not found

Tags: php, laravel

Consider we reference a non existing class in the console context (tinker/tinkerwell etc):

`Anything::method();`

This will give `PHP Error:  Class "Anything" not found ...`.

Is there some way I can instruct the Laravel framework to catch these errors "globally" and let a handler do something? It is not an alternative to insert try/catch in the code to be executed in tinker, nor to use statical analysis since it must be handled at runtime.

*Note, I actually *want* to refer to these "not-yet-created" classes for a scratchpad experiment. Then catch it, create that missing file or similar...*

I tried this in Handler.php:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (Error $e) {
        dd("catched by renderable");
    });

    $this->reportable(function (Error $e, $request) {
        dd("catched by reportable");
    });     
}
```

But I suspect this can only be used for Exceptions and not for Errors.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to refer to correct class names? Otherwise, implement `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php`.

Comment: I want to refer to not yet created classes for an scratchpad experiment. Can I implemented `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php` also for Errors?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel docs provides a section destinated to error handling:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors

Where you can set up custom behaviors to exceptions, like send it to a custom view when happens exact error:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#rendering-exceptions

```
use App\Exceptions\InvalidOrderException;
 
/**
 * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (InvalidOrderException $e, $request) {
        return response()->view('errors.invalid-order', [], 500);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this for the Error class, but I could not get it to work. Not sure if it is really possible since it is a "fatal error". Updated question with example. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

These errors are fairly easy to use static code analysis to find. In my opinion no code should be shipped to production, with an unknown class error.

The tool the community uses for this at the moment is `larastan`. It has more advanced features, and works in a level range from 0 to 9, in your case rule level 0 will be more than enough to find these problems.

```
composer require nunomaduro/larastan:^2.0 --dev
```

Create a config file in the root named `phpstan.neon`.

```
includes:
    - ./vendor/nunomaduro/larastan/extension.neon

parameters:

    paths:
        - app

    level: 0
```

You can analyze your code, and find these errors.

```
./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse
```

Comment: I actually want to refer to not yet created classes for an scratchpad experiment so the question is if these errors can be catched and handled at runtime. So its not really solvable by static analysis. Thanks though!

Comment: But you question did not include these facts before this. why is try catch not applicable?

Comment: Correct, updated the question to hopefully make it clearer. try/catch defeats purpose of the question